# Unit test roslyn component

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, analyzer

I've seen posts around that essentially come down to "to unit test, parse text A and expect text B".
With my component, I've tried to separate the analyser into many parts and I'd like to test individual parts. For example, I have a method that takes a MethodDeclarationSyntax and extracts information from that to pass on to another component that may take a ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to create a MethodDeclarationSyntax let alone creating one with some hardcoded value that I can use to test various cases.

Comment: https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the methods in the [`SyntaxFactory` class](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/SyntaxFactory.cs,4fb8e71831d97959) to create syntax nodes.

Or paste your code into https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/ to generate those calls for you.